# Background image doesn't display

Tags: css

I want a background on my body, but I can't get it to work...

I already tried changing the path, I've checked it multiple times and as an image it works.

```
 /**Body**/
 body {
     background: url(background: url(img/fond.jpg) repeat;
 }

 .header {
     background: #404040;
     height: 35px;
     width: 100%;
 }

 /**Wrap**/
 .wrap {
     width: 960px;
     margin: 0 auto;
 }

 /**Contenu**/
 .contenu-haut {
     background: url(img/contenuhaut.jpg)no-repeat;
     width: 1200px;
     height: 41px;
 }

 .blog {
     background: url(img/contenuhaut.jpg) repeat-x;
     width: 1200px;

 }
```

Comment: `background: url(background: url(img/fond.jpg) repeat;` should be: `background: url(img/fond.jpg) repeat;`

Answer (score 4):

It should be like this:

```
body {
  background: url(img/fond.jpg) repeat;
}
```

Comment: ... was so invested in it that i didn't realized... Feel like an idiot, thank you .. ^^

Answer (score 0):

```
body{
  background-image: url("img_girl.jpg");

  /* Full height */
  height: 100%; 

  /* Center and scale the image nicely */
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body  {
  background-image: url("Desktop\1.JPG");
  background-color: #cccccc;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h1>The background-image Property</h1>

<p>Hello World!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Separation of concerns is a key concept in early development. I would wholeheartedly stay away from keeping CSS and HTML in the same exact file.